# Rvest: How to set values on a form without names

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a form that has the following features -- with "text" being the box for username in this case.

```
form = html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]
print(form)

<form> 'login' (GET )
  <input text> '':
  <input password> '':
  <input submit> '': log in
>
```

I dug more into what the form looked like:

```
> form$fields[1]
$`NULL`
$`name`
NULL

$type
[1] "text"

$value
NULL

$checked
NULL

$disabled
NULL

$readonly
NULL

$required
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "input"
```

I'm not sure how to alter the text and password perameters without a specific name to reference. This didn't work, for reference:

```
filled_form = set_values(form,
                         '' = "email@email.com",
                         '' = "p@ssword")
```

Nor did this work:

```
filled_form = set_values(form,
                         form$fields[1]$value = "email@email.com",
                         form$fields[2]$value ="p@ssword")
```

Any thoughts? Apologies in advance that I can't share the URL.

Comment: OK I figured that out by setting the values outside the form.

Comment: However, still having trouble with this error even if I change the form$url... `Submitting with 'NULL'
Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
  Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].`

Comment: Can you give the web link to the form? It is difficult to help you without the html link.